# WPF convert boolean binding to a string like Yes or No

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, boolean

As my Title says I need to write in my DataGrid instead of True or False Yes/No for boolean value I am getting from database,

I've been researching and I've found some helpers like :

```
public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T FalseValue { get; set; }
    public T TrueValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return FalseValue;
        else
            return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
    }
}
```

But question is how to apply this correctly in XAML,

I tried adding this to my XAML:

```
<local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BooleanToStringConverter" FalseValue="No" TrueValue="Yes" />
```

But than I got following errors:

> Error 2   ''local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 13, position 10.' XML
>   is not valid.
>
> Error 4   BoolToStringConverter is not supported in a Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
>
> Error 7   The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is
>   contained in "IDictionary".

So my questions is how to make this works in my XAML, probably I need to include something or whatever, I am really new to WPF so right now it is really hard for me to find solutiokn :/

Anyway
Thanks guys,
Cheers

EDIT: (MY XAML CODE)

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Forms.Products"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Products" Height="768" Width="1024">
    <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtgProducts" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" EnableRowVirtualization ="True" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#d3d3d3" AlternatingRowBackground="#E0E4E5" AlternationCount="2"  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" FontSize="16" RowHeight="30" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Background="White" Margin="5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowHeaderWidth="0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>

                <DataGrid.Resources>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                    </Style>

                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="LightBlue"/>

                </DataGrid.Resources>   

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductTitle}"        Header="ProductName"  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Header="Is it new product(Yes/No)."  Foreground="Black"  FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana"  Width="10*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

EDIT:

INCLUDED IN RESOURCES OF DATAGRID

[image]

INCLUDED ON TOP OF DOCUMENT:

[image]

Comment: Error 2: You don't have an `xmlns:local=...` declaration in your XAML. Error 4: XAML doesn't (easily) support generic types. Remove the type parameter from your converter class and declare the FalseValue and TrueValue properties as `object`. Error 7: The `<local:BoolToStringConverter .../>` declaration should be inside a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: @Clemens I did edit on my question, I posted full XAML, could you take a look please and provide answer where I should put what and I will mark it as answer, I'm really struggling to put all this stuffs on places where they should be :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Clemens' comment says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961235/wpf-convert-boolean-binding-to-a-string-like-yes-or-no#comment73016929_42961235), you need to add the necessary XML namespace declaration, provide a non-generic type, and declare your converter object appropriately (it can either go in a dictionary, with `x:Key...`, or you can specify it inline).

The changes would look something like this (I've omitted all of the XAML that does not appear to directly relate to your question):

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Forms.Products"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Forms"
        Title="Products" Height="768" Width="1024">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BooleanToStringConverter"
                                             FalseValue="No" TrueValue="Yes" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>   
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}"
                                    Header="Is it new product(Yes/No)."/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note the `xmlns:local...` declaration added to the `Window` element, and the location of the `<local:BoolToStringConverter.../>` element in the `DataGrid.Resources` element.

For what it's worth, since the `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` properties are being set in the resource declaration, I would actually give the resource a more description key, like `"BooleanToYesNoConverter"`.

I note that your C# example shows a class named `BoolToValueConverter<T>`, while the type name you use in the XAML is `BoolToStringConverter`. This is fine, as long as you fix the generic type issue by specializing your generic subclass. Which you can do easily:

```
class BoolToStringConverter : BoolToValueConverter<string> { }
```

With the above changes, everything you want will work fine. However, I would recommend a slightly different implementation for `BoolToValueConverter<T>`:

```
class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T TrueValue { get; set; }
    public T FalseValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? FalseValue : ((bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Note: this implementation precludes the use of "null" as the
        // value for TrueValue. Probably not an issue in 99.94% of all cases,
        // but something to consider, if one is looking to make a truly 100%
        // general-purpose class here.
        return value != null && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T)value, TrueValue);
    }
}
```

That is, use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()` for your equality comparison. This can be slightly more efficient than using the virtual `object.Equals()` override, especially for value types (not an issue in your example, but could be in other scenarios).

Comment: Thanks a lot on detailed explanation, from few errors now we are on only 1, its says like my local:BoolValue.. does not exist in namespace I included, :/ Check for my EDIT please

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: if the C# code is actually what you've shown in your post, you're using the wrong type name for the resource. You should be using `<local:BoolToStringConverter .../>` and not `<local:BoolToValueConverter .../>` as shown in your edit. Do also note that, if you've just added the class, you'll get that error in the XAML editor, until the next time you compile. But here, it seems you are just using the wrong name.

Comment: This solved my issue, but at the end I've found solution to return correspondible string from database IF(BooleanToCheck,'Yes','No'); :) Thanks anyway